# Sublist predicate in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, logic

I am trying to define a predicate `sublist(X,Y)` in Prolog which is true when the elements of the list `X` all appear in the list `Y`, in the same order as they are in `X`.

My approach is to take the head of `X`, find the first instance of the head in `Y` and cut the list right before this first instance, then repeating this with the tail of `X` until the tail equals the empty list.

I have written the helper predicate `cut(X,Y,Z)` which is true if `Z` is the resulting list of cutting everything before the first instance of `X` in the list `Y`.

My code is as follows:

```
cut(_,[],[_|_]) :- false.
cut(X,[H|T],[H|T]) :- X = H, !.
cut(X,[_|T],Y) :- cut(X,T,Y).

sublist([],[]).
sublist([],[_|_]).
sublist([A|B],C) :- cut(A,C,Z), sublist(B,Z).
```

When I query

```
?- sublist(L,[1,2,3]).
```

Instead of giving all sublists of `[1,2,3]` Prolog gives me the following output:

```
L = [] ;
L = [1] ;
L = [1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1|...] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1|...] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1|...]
```

I fail to see my mistake. Can anyone point it out to me?

Comment: You don't need the rule `cut(_,[],[_|_]) :- false.` Just its absence will cause queries that look like `cut(_,[],[_|_]).` to fail since it doesn't match a succeeding rule. And did  you try doing a `trace`? Or did  you try just testing `cut/3` itself? Is there a reason you're creating `cut/3` and not just using `select/3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: `cut/3` does **not pop** from the list if it finds an element.

The first answer `L = [].` is the result of the second clause firing. Now the next answer is generated by the last clause. So what happens is:

```
sublist(A,[1,2,3]) :- % C = [1,2,3]
    cut([A|B],[1,2,3],[H|T]) :- % H = 1, T = [2,3], Z = [1,2,3]
        A = H, % A=1
        !.
    sublist(B,[1,2,3]).
```

So since the second clause of `cut/3` fires, the second and third argument are equivalent and thus `cut/3` does **not "pop" from the list**.

A way to solve this and guarantee progression is popping from the list, with:

```
cut(_,[],[_|_]) :- false.
cut(H,[H|T],T) :-
    !.
cut(X,[_|T],Y) :-
    cut(X,T,Y).
```

(I also took the liberty to replace `X` with `H` in the head of the clause making it more elegant). Now it generates:

```
?- sublist(L,[1,2,3]).
L = [] ;
L = [1] ;
L = [1, 2] ;
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

Note that the answer does not generate all lists: for instance `L = [2,3]` is also a valid answer. The reason this does not work is because `cut/3` has `!` and thus does not allow to introduce additional elements. You can solve this with:

```
cut(_,[],[_|_]) :- false.
cut(H,[H|T],T).
cut(X,[_|T],Y) :-
    cut(X,T,Y).
```

Now we obtain:

```
?- sublist(L,[1,2,3]).
L = [] ;
L = [1] ;
L = [1, 2] ;
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
L = [1, 3] ;
L = [2] ;
L = [2, 3] ;
L = [3] ;
false.
```

Nevertheless you can solve the problem quite elegantly without using a help predicate at all. We can first construct a predicate that validates/creates lists:

```
list([]).
list([_|T]) :-
    list(T).
```

Next we state that if `X` is empty, you do not really care what sort of list is at the right:

```
sublist([],L) :-
    list(L).
```

And finally if `X` is not empty, we need to obtain `HX` (the head of `X`) somewhere. If we find it, we can either decide to "accept" it, and pop both lists, or we can decide to look for another `HX`, like:

```
sublist([HX|TX],[HX|TY]) :-
    sublist(TX,TY).
sublist(X,[_|TY]) :-
    X = [_|_],
    sublist(X,TY).
```

The `X = [_|_]` in the last clause in not strictly necessary, but prevents generating duplicate results with the `sublist([],X)` clause.

Or putting it together:

```
list([]).
list([_|T]) :-
    list(T).

sublist([],L) :-
    list(L).
sublist([HX|TX],[HX|TY]) :-
    sublist(TX,TY).
sublist(X,[_|TY]) :-
    X = [_|_],
    sublist(X,TY).
```

This generates:

```
?- sublist(L,[1,2,3]).
L = [] ;
L = [1] ;
L = [1, 2] ;
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
L = [1, 3] ;
L = [2] ;
L = [2, 3] ;
L = [3] ;
false.
```

Or:

```
?- sublist([1,2,3],L).
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, _G2440] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, _G2440, _G2443] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, _G2440, _G2443, _G2446] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, _G2440, _G2443, _G2446, _G2449] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, _G2440, _G2443, _G2446, _G2449, _G2452] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, _G2440, _G2443, _G2446, _G2449, _G2452, _G2455] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, _G2440, _G2443, _G2446, _G2449, _G2452, _G2455|...] ;
```

Or:

```
?- sublist([1,2,3],[1,2,4,5,3,6]).
true ;
```

Comment: You don't need the rule `cut(_,[],[_|_]) :- false.`. It's superfluous, since `cut(_,[],[_|_])` will fail due to the absence of a succeeding/matching rule.

Comment: @lurker: well actually one does not need `cut` at all. Currently I am writing a more elegant way to solve the problem.

Comment: Right. But if you want to define such a `cut/3`, you don't need that clause. Also, there's already a `select/3` defined in ISO Prolog. :) But, you did point out the OP's mistake in their predicate, which is what they were asking for. :)